# RStudio: Error in install.packages : path[1]="XXXXX\R\win-library\3.4": An unexpected network error occurred

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

I'm a little embarrassed to ask this, but I'm having trouble finding the answer.  I'm trying to set up R for the first time on a new computer.

I keep getting the following error when trying to install any package in RStudio.

**RStudio: Error in install.packages : path[1]="XXXXX\R\win-library\3.4": An unexpected network error occurred**

My theories are:

(1) The path is set in the wrong location.
(2) Do not have permissions to download packages.

I've tried a lot of things already.  I'm sure I'm not the first person to have this problem, but I'm still struggling to find the answer.  Any suggestions to get past this?

Comment: Well, does the path listed in the error message exist (I'm assuming you've removed some bits with the XXXX)? Can you view it's contents? Do you have permissions to write to that folder? Is it installed on some remote network drive rather than your local PC hard drive?

Comment: Path exists, I can view contents, I have permission, but it is on a remote network drive not a local hard drive.  I have a few other computers set up the same way.